# Unity is changing the object names at .dae import

Tags: import, unity-game-engine

I am importing a .dae (originaly CAD from CATIA V5) of a model containing several objects sharing the same name, but are differently located in the hierarchy.

At import, Unity is adding an index at the end of the objects names.

For instance, 4 objects using the same name, such as "Wheel", will be imported as "Wheel 1", "Wheel 2", "Wheel 3" and "Wheel 4"

I need to keep the original names.

Would you know what I can do to make sure the original names are kept?

Thanks

Eric

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the asset post processor to override this behaviour. See http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/AssetPostprocessor.html for more details.

Comment: Thanks Flunk, modifying the object names once the asset file is imported is one option, but I d rather avoid having Unity change the names in the first place. Is there anyway to have control on that, or to avoid it? Thanks

Comment: I'd have to check my code, it's been a while since I've done work on asset pipelines.

Comment: Hi Flunk, would you have additional info by any chance? This small issue is driving nuts...